# Why does NSManagedObject not get inserted into a child NSManagedObjectContext when the context is initialised inline?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using child `NSManagedObjectContext`s in my iOS app as a scratchpad. I am using an extension of `NSManagedObjectContext` to create child contexts, as follows:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    func childContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType = .mainQueueConcurrencyType) -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: concurrencyType)
        childContext.parent = self
        return childContext
    }
}
```

I was experiencing repeated errors with the following message for one part of my app when inserting a new `NSManagedObject` into a new child context (created from the `viewContext` of a `NSPersistentContainer`):

> CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object after it has been removed from its context

This was strange, as other parts of the app -- which also used child contexts -- worked fine. Eventually, I narrowed the cause down to a small difference in the way I am inserting the new `NSManagedObject` (of entity name "Book") into the new child context. The following works as expected:

```
let childContext = container.viewContext.childContext()
let object1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Book", into: childContext)
print(object1.managedObjectContext == nil)
// prints "false"
```

However, if I create the child context inline (i.e. **not assigned to a variable**, the managed object is **not** inserted into the context):

```
let object2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Book", into: container.viewContext.childContext())
print(object2.managedObjectContext == nil)
// prints "true"
```

This seems odd to me and can't figure it out. Everything is running on the main thread. I've also created a [Swift playground](https://gist.github.com/AndrewBennet/ec17965d3605efc61fb7453e301d5ad1) reproducing this behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed objects have a `managedObjectContext` property, but it's a weak reference. That means that having the managed object doesn't stop the context from being deallocated. If the context gets deallocated, the `managedObjectContext` property is automatically set to nil.

In your first code snippet, `childContext` exists as a local variable in the code that creates the managed object. After you insert the new object, it still exists in the local scope, so the `managedObjectContext` property still points to the context. The `childContext` variable keeps a strong reference, so the object still exists.

In the second snippet, the child context only exists as an argument to `insertNewObject`. Once that method returns, the context goes out of scope. Since there are no strong references to the context, it gets deallocated, and `object2.managedObjectContext` is automatically set to nil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had just started to look into the `managedObjectContext` reference and saw it was `weak`, so figured something like this was happening. One thing still doesn't quite make sense to me though: my app uses approach 1 (detailed in the question) and doesn't keep a strong reference to the scratchpad context, and the context goes out of scope soon after the object is inserted. However, the context _doesn't_ seem to get deallocated in that case...
Is the deallocation not performed if there exist string references to objects in the context?

Comment: The `let` is a strong reference in the current scope. The effect of that depends on what else happens before leaving the scope, but managed objects never cause a strong reference to their context.

Comment: In my code, nothing else is capturing a strong reference to the context and it goes out of scope after the object creation: I am using a reference only to the managed object (which I mistakenly thought was enough) and passing that into presented view controllers. See, for example, [this line](https://github.com/AndrewBennet/ReadingList/blob/c955fccb9df6abafc8cfd7ef3ff09bcac1c119b4/ReadingList/ViewControllers/Add/SearchOnline.swift#L178).

Regardless of why this way works, it seems clear that my approach is wrong, and I should capture a strong reference to both the object and the context...

Comment: I take it back - I was wrong: I was capturing a strong reference to the context in a different view controller before it went out of scope in the function where the object was instantiated. Thanks for your help.